# How to aggregate features from a long table for Spark ML

Tags: apache-spark, hive, pyspark

I'd like to build a pyspark ML model from data stored in a hive table. The data looks like this:

```
ID | value
---+------
1  |  100
1  |  101
1  |  102
2  |  101
2  |  103
```

Using pure hive, I could optionally use `collect_set` to collapse the values into hive arrays producing something like this:

```
ID | value
---+-----------
1  | (100, 101, 102)
2  | (101, 103)
```

The values are categorical features. For this particular use case I'm fine to consider them as indices to a sparse vector of 1, but it'd be nice to have a solution for general categoricals a la `StringIndexer()`.  What I'd like to do is to gather the values into a feature vector which I could then feed to one of the classifiers.

I tried using a UDF to convert the arrays into VectorUDT and then featurize with VectorIndexer(), but when I tried this it complained that all vectors are not the same length.

What's the proper way to gather these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing stops you from using `collect_set` in Spark SQL as well. It is just quite expensive. If you don't mind that all you need is just a bunch of imports:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions.import collect_set, udf, col
from pyspark.ml.linag import SparseVector

n = df.max("value").first[0] + 1

to_vector = udf(lambda xs: SparseVector(n, {x: 1.0 for x in xs})

(df
    .groupBy("id", collect_set(col("value")).alias("values"))
    .select("id", to_vector(col("values")).alias("features")))
```

Comment: But doesn't that leave me in the same place as when I get it from hive, which is to say vectors of varying lengths that don't want to featurize?

Comment: Looking back with the benefit of hindsight, the `n` in your udf solves my problem. I ended up preprocessing the collect_set, and then used a very slightly different udf: ` udf(lambda l, maxlen: Vectors.sparse(maxlen, {v:1.0 for v in l}),VectorUDT())` One important caveat - for this to work the array that's being passed in must be sorted!